# How can I accurately lerp Colors over seconds?

Tags: unity, color, timestep, lerp, realtime

I have some code to lerp between two colors over a set number of seconds, and the lerp works fine:

```
private Color lerpingColor;

private IEnumerator LerpColorsOverTime(Color startingColor, Color endingColor, float time)
{
    float step = 0.0f;
    while (step < 1.0f)
    {
        step += Time.deltaTime / time;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(Time.deltaTime);
        lerpingColor = Color.Lerp(startingColor, endingColor, step);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the lerp time takes longer than the time I provide in my parameter.  For example, `LerpColorsOverTime(Color.white, Color.black, 5.0f);` takes over 8 seconds to lerp.

My best guess is that I am being very inefficient in the way I am lerping.  I tried accounting for the calculation time, but it does not seem to work.  In the particular case shown, it is because `calculationTime` is always 0, since the code to update the time is never run between my `Time.time` checks.  I tried various approaches, with this being my best:

```
private Color lerpingColor;

private IEnumerator LerpColorsOverTime(Color startingColor, Color endingColor, float time)
{
    float calculationTime = Time.time;
    float step = 0.0f;
    while (step < 1.0f)
    {
        step += Time.deltaTime / time;
        calculationTime = Time.time - calculationTime;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(Time.deltaTime - calculationTime);
        calculationTime = Time.time;
        lerpingColor = Color.Lerp(startingColor, endingColor, step);
    }
}
```

I also tried other variations of `Time.time`, such as `DateTime.Now.Miliseconds / 1000.0f` and `Time.realtimeSinceStartup`, but they failed as well.

How can I make this code efficient enough to run in the expected time, or make some sort of change with the seemingly same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `Time.deltaTime` is the time between the current frame and the **last** frame. When calling `new WaitForSecondsRealtime(Time.deltaTime)` you "guess" the next frame will be in `Time.deltaTime` seconds. Which may not be true ! And, since Unity is not very precise, you may wait for 2 frames instead of one, resulting in your problem. Yielding `null` will wait for the next frame.

```
private IEnumerator LerpColorsOverTime(Color startingColor, Color endingColor, float time)
{
    float inversedTime = 1 / time ; // Compute this value **once**
    for( step = 0.0f; step < 1.0f ; step += Time.deltaTime * inversedTime )
    {
        lerpingColor = Color.Lerp(startingColor, endingColor, step);
        yield return null ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely an oversight on my part.  Thanks!  I am using `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` now, and it works.